# Store all GET requests in a single variable PHP

Tags: php, variables, post, get

I am trying to store any and all variables sent to the site in a single variable (just for logging purposes.)

So if a user goes to www.mysite.com and put on a ?id=4&auth=230984721839

I want to grab both of those GETs and store them in a variable such as $gets

I was trying:

```
$gets = print_r($_GET);
$posts = print_r($_POST);
```

But it did not work. Is this even possible? I don't want the user know I am capturing these.

I would also like to grab POSTs too!

Comment: What do you want the contents of `$gets` to look like?

Comment: @jondavidjohn well, I'd like it exactly as it was sent. So if sent id=3&auth=1 I want it to show just that

Comment: Take a look in `$_SERVER`, one of those values may have what you want.  Do `var_dump($_SERVER)` to see what's in there.  I think it's `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want both `$_GET`and `$_POST` as query strings, you can do this:

```
$gets = http_build_query($_GET);
$posts = http_build_query($_POST);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can add a flag to [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to tell it to return the result instead of outputting it.

```
$gets = print_r($_GET, true);
$posts = print_r($_POST, true);
```

However, you may want to look into [serializing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the associative array instead.

**Update**

Based on your comments on your question I suppose you really want:

```
$gets = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$posts = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: For logging purpose, it might be better to get unparsed data to catch any illegal queries.

Answer (score 2):

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

This will give you unparsed query, so you can catch any invalid URLs which might be useful for logging purpose.

Comment: @Michael does this grab POSTs too?

Comment: @JDAudi: POST variables are not part of the query string, so, no.

Comment: I would like to grab POST variables as well!

Comment: there is a separate variable `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`. Also, you might be interested in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` which will tell you what method was used.

Comment: [`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is not reliable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you might appreciate that all the parameters, both GET and POST ones, are collected in `$_REQUEST`.

Second, don't use `print_r`. That will print the variable out, and not give you any sensible result. Instead, just say

```
$params = $_REQUEST;
```

If you want the raw data, then you can get it as in @MichałŠrajer's answer (GET) and comment (POST). So,

```
$get = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$post = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Comment: I don't think `http_get_request_body` is a standard PHP function.  The docs page says it's in `pecl_http`.

Answer (score 1):

By this code you can get any POST or GET values and then -maybe- put them into array for later use

```
    foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value ) {
        ##Do what you want here - may be push values into array here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For storing purpose there is another possibility, and it is to [`serialize`](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the $_GET array.

```
$data = serialize($_GET);
```

And then you store `$data` in your database.

For example, if your get string is `?foo=bar`

you get this string `a:1:{s:3:"foo";s:3:"bar";}`

You can ever deserialize it with `unserialize($data);`